# usbmount scripting

Tags: linux, command-line

I'm trying to create a script that will automatically format a USB flash drive when inserted, However there is an internal usb flash drive in the device, how would I go about making an exclusion of that device (unit will never turn on again if this drive is formatted).
Thanks!

Comment: Formatting a flash drive when inserted sounds a bit risky. Are you going to ask for permission first?

Answer (score 0):

You could check for the USB ID (obtain it via `lsusb`).